# Positioning a Navigation Bar to the right of a Logo while still being Responsive

Tags: html, css

PICTURE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvaQw.jpg

I have a navigation in my header (Main Navigation), which I want to be positioned like shown in the picture. I have tried displaying it like an inline-block element, floating it to the right and it kinda works. The problem is that the navigation won't be horizontally aligned with the logo while still being responsive.

My header consists of:

```
<header class="primary-header">
    <img src="[SOURCE]" alt="Logo">
    <h1>[WEBSITE TITLE]</h1>

    <nav class="nav secondary-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
<header/>
```

My CSS:

```
.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.primary-header {
    padding: 15px;
}

.primary-header img {
    width: 17.5%;
    height: auto;
}

/*Main Navigation*/
.primary-nav { 
    vertical-align: middle;
}

h1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I simply can't find a solution on how to position the main navigation like shown in the picture while still being responsive/fluid by using CSS. If anyone could help pointing me in the right direction, I would be very thankful!

Comment: Can you add the css that you already have so we can have a start point to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using flex box like this:

```
.primary-header {
    padding: 15px;
    display: flex;        /*important line*/
    align-items: center;  /*important line*/
}
```

Here a working snippet (see in full page, here is to narrow)

```css
.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.primary-header {
    padding: 15px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.primary-header img {
    width: 17.5%;
    height: auto;
}

/*Main Navigation*/
.primary-nav { 
    vertical-align: middle;
}

h1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header class="primary-header">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijdH.jpg?s=328&g=1" alt="Logo">
    <h1>[WEBSITE TITLE]</h1>

    <nav class="nav secondary-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
<header/>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm!

Comment: @MysticSheik I'm glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
img,
h1,
nav {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: This almost works. The only problem is that the main navigation is placed at the bottom of the image height, not in the middle.